# NGINX 502 Bad Gateway using docker and jmeter

Tags: docker, nginx, jmeter, nginx-config

I am using nginx on docker along with 2 microservices, also on docker, all are on local. I am using JMeter to do load testing with a large amount of users.

The thing is that I get the 502 Bad Gateway error in many requests (60%-70%).

From my point of view I think it is due to CPU and memory limitation, as all the local share the same resources, in the task manager these are at 100%.

The nginx.config file is as follows:

```
worker_processes 4;

events {
    worker_connections 2048;
}

http {
    proxy_connect_timeout 60s;
    proxy_read_timeout 30s;

    upstream loadbalancer{
        server 172.18.0.3:8083;
        server 172.18.0.4:8084;
    }

    server {
        listen 8080;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://loadbalancer/;
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know what this is due to? Am I right in thinking that it is due to CPU and memory limitations?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As per [HTTP Status 502](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/502) description:

> The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) 502 Bad Gateway server error response code indicates that the server, while acting as a gateway or proxy, received **an invalid response from the upstream server**.

So it means that at least one of your microservices has failed to provide a proper response to Nginx.

So you need to identify the root cause of the failure by analyzing your microservices logs, [profiling their code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_performance_analysis_tools) and so son.

In general running a load generator on the same machine as the system under test is not the best idea as both system under test and JMeter can be resource intensive and will "fight" for memory, CPU and network. So you won't get good results. Also the results cannot be extrapolated as they don't scale linearly so you cannot state that if your system supports 100 000 users on 4GB of RAM it will support 200 000 users on 8GB of RAM. You need to either test the system's performance on production environment or as close to production as possible in terms of hardware, software, data volumes, etc.

Once you obtain some results you can repeat the lesser test on a scaled-down environment and use it as a baseline for [regression testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_testing), but initial [stress test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_performance_testing#Stress_testing) should be done on a prod-like environment.

More information on this and other important topics: [Load Testing Best Practices](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-best-practices)